# Python For loop not iterating through directories

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Am trying to delete the files between two dates in a folder contains several sub folders.
I want to keep the latest the 14 days files and to delete the remaining 16 files in a month in all subfolders.
My current script is deleting first directory `D:\S135\firstdirectory` and going to else block without touching remaining folders.

```
Error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:
```

The code

```
import os
import time
import datetime

def main():
    start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2022-03-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
    to_delete = 'D:\S135'

    if os.path.exists(to_delete):
        if os.path.isdir(to_delete):
            for root_folder, folders, files in os.walk(to_delete):
                for file in files:
                    curpath = os.path.join(to_delete, file)
                    file_modified = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(curpath))
                    if datetime.datetime.now() - file_modified > datetime.timedelta(days=14):   
                        if file_modified > start_date :
                            print(curpath)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # invoking main function
    main()
```

Comment: The filenames are relative to `root_folder`, not `to_delete`. So use `os.path.join(root_folder, file)`

Comment: There's no `else` block in the code, what are you referring to?

Comment: You should use a raw string when the pathname uses backslash. `r"D:\S135"`

Comment: The script doesn't delete anything.

Comment: You don't need to cal lboth `os.path.exists` and `os.path.isdir`. If it doesn't exist, `isdir()` will return `False`.

Comment: @Barmar is correct, the issue is with the code. Every time the code changes directory and goes into a directory that is inside the to_delete path, the file path changes. for example: if a file (bar.txt) exists in the 'foo' folder inside the to_delete path (D:\S135) then the file path is 'D:\S135\foo\bar.txt' .. But your code searches in 'D:\S135\bar.txt' -> which doesn't exist

Comment: Yes i have not included else block, that will just say No records

Comment: @Barmar Edited the code now

Comment: Don't edit the question to contain the answer. Then my answer makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks, It is working now, but how to exclude one folder "D:\recycle\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
                    curpath = os.path.join(to_delete, file)
```

to

```
                    curpath = os.path.join(root_folder, file)
```

because the names in `files` are relative to the current directory of the recursion, not the folder that you started from.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `topdown=true`

```
for root_folder, folders, files in os.walk(to_delete, topdown=true)
```

Comment: yes getting same error

Comment: Why would this be needed?